# How can I view only one task list in Jorte?

Tags: task-management, jorte

Suppose I'm at the store, and all I want to view is my "Stuff to Buy at the Store" list in Jorte. How can I view only that list instead of all the tasks on any list?

Answer (score 0):

In the application, click on the 'Tasks & Memos' area. There should be a `Task list` button; click on it.

There, you can select and deselect the lists you want to show. If you only wanted to show a single list, you can uncheck the rest of the lists and click `Close`.

Now, this isn't designed to be used to quickly show and hide lists. Rather, it seems more like a preference. If you want multiple lists and the ability to quickly load just one on demand, I would recommend an app designed specifically for lists, such as [List Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cjb.listmaster).

I use Jorte, but only for my calendars. It isn't well suited for separate lists, but rather a simple todo list.